# Check if a user is an Administrator (vb)

Tags: vb.net, rights

If i have a username account in a STRING,how can i check if is an Administrator?

I'm looking for something like that:

```
 Dim user as string = "test"
 Dim isAdmin as Boolean = false
 isAdmin = user.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)
```

The user that i have to check ISN'T the current user.

Comment: Don't ask the same question again, you've asked this 3 times now.

Comment: My question is different and idk how do it ... I haven't received an answer jet.

Comment: I did find this as well, but it's a little more involved and needs a password.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841699

Comment: I have to use without password =$

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below;

```
Imports System.Security.Principal


Dim W_Id = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
Dim WP = new WindowsPrincipal(W_Id)
Dim isAdmin as Boolean = WP.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)
```

Either you call it onLoad() or you can wrap it all in a function, which you can call throughout your codes.

Comment: Don't work ... If i run with RUN AS this code check the account in RUN AS not the current windows account.